# Angular material nvd3

Tags: angular-material, angular-nvd3

I am using the combination of Angular material and NVD3 while investigating why tooltips are not visible for me.

I have chopped and cloned the example provided from http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart to plunker and it is something like this:

[image]

While the same one on angular material with nvd3 wrapper looks like this (no tooltip)

[image]

Was wandering if anyone had a similar experience and how it got resolved.

Declaration:

```
<nvd3 options="chartChartOptions" data="chartData"></nvd3>
```

and inside the controller

```
  $scope.chartChartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'multiBarChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 45,
                    left: 45
                },
                clipEdge: true,
                duration: 500,
                stacked: true,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Time (ms)',
                    showMaxMin: false,
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format(',f')(d);
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                    axisLabelDistance: -20,
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                    }
                }
            }
        };


  $scope.chartData = [{"key":"Stream0","values":[{"x":1,"y":1.2191711805077412,"y0":0,"series":0,"key":"Stream0","size":1.2191711805077412,"y1":1.2191711805077412}]},{"key":"Stream1","values":[{"x":1,"y":2.8682672436400285,"y0":1.2191711805077412,"series":1,"key":"Stream1","size":2.8682672436400285,"y1":4.08743842414777}]},{"key":"Stream2","values":[{"x":1,"y":0.18054369373704626,"y0":4.08743842414777,"series":2,"key":"Stream2","size":0.18054369373704626,"y1":4.2679821178848165}]}];
```

For versions of libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material-data-table/0.9.11/md-data-table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-csv/0.3.6/ng-csv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-nvd3/1.0.5/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried trial and error but without help, anyone in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of digging, we had forgotten to include all framework's CSS sheets which would render the graph visible.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this also occurs using the option `useInteractiveGuideline` with `true` value. Thsi is caused because there's a issue between the tooltips options being true. A way to make this work is creating a callback for the tooltip and set "`useInteractiveGuideline:true`"

```
callback: function(chart) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            d3.selectAll('.nvtooltip').style('opacity', 0);
                        }, 100);
                    },
useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                tooltips: true,
```